# Extending a class with a new nested class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection, types

first question so I'm open to advice on effectively participating in the StackOverflow community as well as pertaining to the question.

I'm working on a text-based UI in C#. I have an abstract window class and an abstract control class, each of which implements common functionality for the types that inherit them (e.g. pop-up windows or text box controls). Currently, within a program that might implement the library, a developer would have to create window objects and control objects, and then add the controls to their respective windows, and the windows to a window manager class, like this:

```
var mainWindow = new MainWindow(...);
var textBox1 = new TextBox(...);
mainWindow.AddControl(textBox1);
WindowManager.Add(mainWindow);
```

This works, but it's a bit clunky. Since a control should never have to exist outside of a window, I was hoping to implement the control types as nested types. However, to maintain extensibility of the program, I'd like for there to be a way to extend the window class with new control types. My question is this: Should I use reflection, or rely on developers using container classes to extend the window class? Alternatively, is there a better way to structure the program than how it's currently laid out?

I've also considered using generics, e.g.:

```
public abstract class Window : DrawableObject, IWindow
{
    public void AddControl <T>(object[] constructorArgs) where T : class, IControl
    {

    }
}
```

I'm aiming for ease of implementation without sacrificing extensibility/loose coupling. Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

EDIT: Should clarify, the primary reason for this is to fix some weirdness with how Windows and Controls cooperate. Each control has a parentWindow property which is used to access the window on which a control resides, for various purposes like creating an exit button for a particular window, etc.

Right now, this property is passed to the constructor, but that seems redundant to me since after doing so you have to add the control to the window's control list. I'd like to find a way to set this property when the control is added to a window instead, but restrict this action to when the control is added only, to prevent potential problems if the parentWindow property is changed outside of this context.

Comment: I don't know what you're gaining by adding that generic method really.  If I was using this I'd prefer to be able to construct my object then tell the window to show it, rather than asking the window to construct the object for me.

Comment: You're right. Each control type which supports an activation action takes a delegate `ControlAction(IControl source)` as a constructor argument, and it's very useful to be able to Do Stuff to one control based on input from another, which would be very difficult without being able construct and ref controls outside the window. I could return a ref to the created control, but that would be redundant. Each control also takes an `IWindow parentWindow`, so maybe should add control to its window in its constructor code? Or perhaps set its parentwindow prop when it's added to a window.

Comment: Setting the parent window of a control when it's added to a window seems to make the most sense, but I'd rather not make the parent window's setter public, since in that case it should only be set when added to a window. I might just have to settle though, making it fool-proof is probably a fool's errand.

Answer (score 0):

The way you coded AddControl method:

```
   public void AddControl <T>(object[] constructorArgs)
        where T : class, IControl
   {
   }
```

You intend developers to just provide type and your AddControl method will create an instance of it using constructorArgs. This method itself implicitly forces you to use reflection. Anything else does not stand a chance. Because To Add control of type T, Creating Instance of Control of type T is necessary. Since your Window class does not have a clue about T reflection is the only solution.
To facilitate other approaches, you might want to consider few overloads of AddControl.

```
   public virtual T AddControl <T>()
      where T : class, new(),IControl
   {
        //now you can create instance no reflection required
        var control = new T();
        this.Controls.Add(control);
        return control;
   }

   public void AddControl <T>(T control)
      where T : class, IControl
   {
   }

   public abstract void AddControl <T>(object[] constructorArgs)
      where T : class, IControl;
```

Creating an abstract method passes onus of implementation on  child class and creating new instance of T can be handled the assuming type of T is known there or at-least all cases of known  types of what T might be are handled.
It's a wide scope topic and I guess subjective as well. The best use of OOP is to achieve a design which fits your logical objective whatever that maybe.